# Print name of the binary

Tags: c

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I have been searching but unable to find the answer anywhere else. Its most likely pretty simple, but here goes:

I am asked to write a C program which takes one argument. If I try to give it more than one, it should print a usage message to stderr, with the format `Usage: %s argument\n`, where `%s` is the name of the binary.

It is this last part which I do not understand.

I know it should look like this if it fails:

`$./hello`
Usage: `./hello argument`

Can someone please explain this to me?

EDIT:

Got it working like this:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>


int args_test(int args, char argument[]){

  if(args < 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s argument\n", argument);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  if(args < 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s argument\n", argument);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
  }

  if(args > 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s argument\n", argument);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  return 0;
}

int args_usage(char argument[]){
  printf("Hello, %s!\n", argument);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]){
  if(args < 2 || args > 2){
    args_test(args, argv[0]);
  }
  args_test(args, argv[1]);
  args_usage(argv[1]);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What do you know about the arguments passed to the `main` function (usually called `argc` and `argv`)? Have you tried printing all the strings in `argv` (and don't forget that array indexes are zero-based)?

Comment: I know the argument is a char array (char * argv[]). I tried printing it, but then it just returns "Usage: (null) argument. It seems like they want me to print the name of the file (as they called their file hello). Just in a way that has to do with binary. I guess that thing would add ./

Comment: Usually, the program name is in `argv[0]`, although if the program was started in an unusual way, that might be a null pointer and `argc` might be 0. Most programs ignore that possibility though.

Comment: `char *argv[]` is (essentially) an *array of strings*. You need to print e.g. `argv[0]` up to `argv[argc - 1]`.

Comment: `if(argc > 0) { puts(argv[0]); }` because the executable's name is usually the first string in the array passed.

Comment: @kthonenice `char *argv[]` is not a char array, it is an array of char pointers as written, although due to C converting array parameters to pointer parameters, it is actually a pointer to the first element of an array of char pointers. In any case,  `argv[0]` should be the string you need.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to add @WeatherVanes code to my function, but that didn't work. It does work in main, so I guess its just a little workaround.

Comment: It is supposed to be in `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` so that it can access the arguments, and was just a demo to show where the executable name is.

Comment: Got it working thanks to you :) Please feel free to otherwise bash my solution for best practices though.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hell first of all you can try and hardcode it :) Just kidding.

If you are on linux, you can get binary name withing /proc/pid/exe.

For example:

```
auto ret = readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, sizeof(buf));
if (ret == -1) //error
std::string fpath(buf, ret);
```

Now in fpath you have absolute path to your program. You can parse your program out with function like dirname.

So first you need to get absolute path to char*. This can be done with strcpy

```
char *fullpath = new char[fpath.length()+1];
strcpy(fullpath, fpath.c_str());
std::string dir = dirname(fullpath);
std::string program_name = fpath.substr(dir.length());

printf("Usage: %s argument\n", program_name);
```

And that is it. I will just leave it for you to decide size of the buffer ;)

If you are on Windows, you can use function GetModuleFileName
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

Enjoy

Comment: As OP ask for `./hello Usage: ./hello argument`, use `argv[0]` is way more simple and almost portable everywhere.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.

Comment: Hm, the question is tagged C.